# Checking if a sequence has consecutive identical characters

Tags: python, loops, character, sequence

For this function I'm trying to have it return "True" when a sequence has consecutive identical characters and have it return "False" when a sequence doesn't. For example, `neighboring_twins(1,2,1,4,1)` should return `False` while `neighboring_twins(1,2,3,3,5)` should return `True` because there are two identical characters directly next to each other (the two 3's).

This is the code I have so far. I don't think having Python search for `"ii"` is the right way to do it as I keep getting syntax errors. I wasn't sure how I would instruct Python to search for consecutive identical characters but assumed I should use a for loop.

```
def neighboring_twins(xs):

    for i in xs:
        if ii = True
            return True
        elif ii = False
            return False
```

Edit: I'd like to accomplish this without importing from other modules and in the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pairwise` function from [itertools' recipies](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) will return a list of pairs of consecutive items. From here on, you're just a list comprehension away of what you need:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

def neighboring_twins(xs):
    return any([x for x in pairwise(xs) if x[0]==x[1]])
```

Or, directly, without copying `pairwise`:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def neighboring_twins(xs):
    a, b = tee(xs)
    next(b, None)
    return any([x for x in izip(a, b) if x[0]==x[1]])
```

**EDIT:**
You could achieve the same functionality without using itertools, albeit with some performance degradation:

```
def neighboring_twins(xs):
    return any([x for x in zip(xs, xs[1::]) if x[0]==x[1]])
```

Comment: @famguy74 This snippet works fine on my machine (Python 2.7.12 on Fedora 24). What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I deleted my original comment because I figured out the issue instead of copying it over I rewrote it and there were issues with spacing

Comment: I'm getting the error name "tee" is not defined when I try testing it.

Comment: @famguy74 `tee` and `izip` need to be imported from itertools. I've edited my answer with the right imports.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my original question but I'd like to accomplish this without importing from other modules. This should be doable with loops, datatypes, lists, and functions. I'll revise the original question now.

Comment: @famguy74 A good old fashioned `zip` and some slicing will also do the trick, although a bit slower. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much that seems like the best solution for what Im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You are getting syntax errors because `if ii` is asking the Python interpreter to check the variable `ii` and see if it's true or not. I would recommend iterating through the list and checking the next element to see if it equals the next. `enumerate()` will be useful for you.

I also noticed that you're using `if ii = True` which is assigning the value of True to ii instead of checking if `ii` is True. You probably want `if ii == True`. The `==` checks for equality and a single equals sign assigns a value to a variable.